# Electric fields of finite and infinite conducting plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, conductors

Are the electric fields due to a finite and infinite metal sheet both the same ($\sigma/\epsilon_0$)?
Please explain it in detail, as I am told by my teacher that they are same.

Comment: Can you provide a derivation for electric feild due to a square at a distance of x from surface??

Comment: I just checked you have asked for metal sheets, your instructor is still incorrect, your teacher probably meant that the electric field for any conductor is $\sigma/\epsilon_o$ in close proximity.

Answer (score 0):

The electric field ia certainly not a constant for a finite metal plate. That is completely false. If you're unsure, do the integration.